# scroll problem when adding item to flowlistview in xamairn

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

i facing a problem when adding item dynamically to flowlistview the scroll get stuck for a bit

each time i press more the items get to the view but still there is a stuck in the scroll till i move the screen the scroll get the new heights

i facing a problem when adding item dynamically to flowlistview the scroll get stuck for a bit

each time i press more the items get to the view but still there is a stuck in the scroll till i move the screen the scroll get the new heights

`private async void ContinueClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var list1 = DataService.Instance.stockslist.Where(X => X.StockType == _Cat.StockTypeCode).ToList();
        foreach (var item in list1)
        {
            li.Add(item);
        }

        MostNews.FlowItemsSource = li;
        Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
           MostNews.ScrollTo(li.Last(), ScrollToPosition.End, false));
        //   await Navigation.PushAsync(new SelectCreditCardPage(), true);
    }`

the xaml code

`<controls:FlowListView
            x:Name="MostNews"
            BackgroundColor="{DynamicResource BackgroundColor}"
            FlowColumnCount="2"
            FlowColumnExpand="None"
            HasUnevenRows="False"
            RowHeight="280"
            SeparatorVisibility="None"
            VerticalOptions="StartAndExpand"
            VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Never">
            <controls:FlowListView.FlowColumnTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <pancakeView:PancakeView
                        Margin="5"
                        Padding="5"
                        BackgroundColor="{DynamicResource ItemColor}"
                        CornerRadius="8"
                        Elevation="2"
                        HasShadow="False"
                        HeightRequest="250"
                        HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                        VerticalOptions="StartAndExpand"
                        WidthRequest="{x:OnIdiom Tablet=150,
                                                 Phone=130}">
                        <pancakeView:PancakeView.GestureRecognizers>
                            <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="ProductDetailClick" />
                        </pancakeView:PancakeView.GestureRecognizers>
                        <StackLayout>
                            <forms:CachedImage
                                Aspect="AspectFit"
                                HeightRequest="150"
                                Source="{Binding Imgurl}" />
                            <Label
                                FontFamily="{DynamicResource VerdanaProRegular}"
                                Text="{Binding StockName}"
                                TextColor="{DynamicResource WhiteDarkFontColor}"
                                VerticalOptions="Start" />
                            <Label
                                FontFamily="{DynamicResource VerdanaProRegular}"
                                FontSize="10"
                                HorizontalOptions="Start"
                                Text="{Binding Freeze}"
                                TextColor="{DynamicResource DescLabelColor}"
                                VerticalOptions="Start" />

                            <Label
                                FontFamily="{DynamicResource VerdanaProBold}"
                                FontSize="25"
                                HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand"
                                Text="{Binding Price, StringFormat='{0} ILS'}"
                                TextColor="{DynamicResource DarkLabelTextColor}"
                                VerticalOptions="EndAndExpand" />
                        </StackLayout>
                    </pancakeView:PancakeView>
                </DataTemplate>
            </controls:FlowListView.FlowColumnTemplate>
        </controls:FlowListView>`

Comment: You could try to  use `ObservableCollection <YourMode>` for your itemsource so that it can automatically update the list, don't reset the itemsource like `MostNews. FlowItemsSource = li;`

Comment: i will give try,i noticed when adding flowlist inside scrollview it makes scroll problems, thank you

Comment: Ok,you could have a try.